# Adding params to request url do not work in Angular4

Tags: angular

I'm using mdPaginator like this:

```
<md-paginator
    [length]="mdPag.length"
    [pageSize]="mdPag.pageSize"
    [pageSizeOptions]="mdPag.pageSizeOptions"
    (page)="selectPage($event)">
  </md-paginator>
```

And have a selectPage function:

```
  selectPage(event) {
    // [A]
    // let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams
    // params.set("page", event.pageIndex+1)
    // params.set("per_page", event.pageSize)
    // this.httpClient
    //     .get("/proxy/api/team/order_list", params)
    //     .map(res => res.json())
    // ...

    // [B]
    // this.httpClient
    //     .get(`/proxy/api/team/order_list?page=${event.pageIndex+1}&per_page=${event.pageSize}`)
    //     .map(res => res.json())
    // ...

    // [C]
       this.httpClient
           .get(`/proxy/api/team/order_list?page=${event.pageIndex+1}&per_page=${event.pageSize}`)
           .toPromise()
  }
```

And, my httpClient service do this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, URLSearchParams, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class HttpClient {

  constructor(public http: Http) { }

  createCustomsHeaders(headers: Headers) {
    headers.append("authorization-user", localStorage.getItem('authorization-user'))
  }

  get(url, params?) {
    console.log('HttpClient')

    let headers = new Headers
    this.createCustomsHeaders(headers)
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers, params })

    console.log(url, options)
    return this.http.get(url, options)
  }
  // ...
}
```

I don't know why but only writing like [C] can work well. I mean, on the network, I can see my Request URL is correct, when [A]/[B], the Request URL is '/proxy/api/team/order_list', seems like they do not get params although I can console it in the get function from HttpClient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A massive difference that I see between A, B and C is that they return very differrent types. Please add a return type to your function and IDE will tell you (I hope you are using smart IDE, if not, then Visual Studio Code or IntelliJ are both nice choices that will tell you that your typescript is wrong). And a very good habbit is always to write types explicitly (variables, parameters, function parameters, return types, etc..)

So what I mean is that C returns `Promise<Response>` (definition [here](https://angular.io/api/http/Response)) while A and B both return `Observable<ResponseJsonType>` where `ResponseJsonType` is the type of JSON object that is returned in you http response. I don't know how you use the return object of `selectPage(event)` but that is likely a problem.

Comment: Thanks! you are right, I should write types for helping! Yeah, i'm using VSC now. I know A & B return Observable and C is a Promise. I write these not in the same type was because I was trying, and when i use C can get right request. So don't know why observable's type cannot. But now I know is because I don't know rxjs much so running into this problem(i thought the request will run after I .map() it :( ). Still thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Gikono, if you showed us how you use the result of the function, I could help you with it. But yes, the observables get executed only when you subscribe to them (call `.subscribe(...)`).